# C++ Regex Matching and Pattern Capture

Tags: c++, regex

Regex is quite simple in scripting languages that I am familiar with like bash and perl.  However I am not so adept at this in C++.

This is what I want:

If a string matches this pattern `leg[0-9]+_.*` then capture everything from the first `_` character onwards.  Can someone show me a basic example for how to do this?  I have seen some matching examples but nothing that shows me how to extract sub patterns.

Thanks

EDIT: Is there a way to do this without std::regex? I am limited by an earlier version of gcc, pre-C++11

Comment: `leg[0-9]+_(.*)` then grab the capture

Comment: Take a look at the reference [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)

Comment: it worth to mention that `std::regex` is only c++11 standard (which op didn't tagged ) . It is not available before gcc 4.9

Comment: I guess that you'd be best off using a 3rd party regex lib or just writing it with while/for loops for general string operations. Things like http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/ could prove inspirational if you have no idea of what's going on.

Comment: @user3979986 Could you possibly use an older version of [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Given your restriction fromusing std::regex I think the next choice would be sscanf.

```
char result [64];
sscanf (input, "leg%*[0-9]%63c", result);
```

This matches "leg" followed by an arbitrary number of digits, but (thanks to the asterisk) doesn't assign any of that to anything. Then it reads the remainder (up to 63 characters) into result. The obvious shortcomings are that the result is an array of char instead of std::string and the fact that many aren't familiar with scanf scanset conversions. A third potential shortcoming is that "0-9" in a scanset technically isn't defined--but essentially all compilers interpret it the obvious way. If you need strict portability use "0123456789" instead.